# Advanced Custom Fields not saving data

Tags: wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a site using ACF plugin for many custom post types, and after some time of use, new added fields cant save data. After I type and press the button to update the post, the text will be gone. 
Its also happening randomly with some old fields.
There is nothing to do with the source code as some pages using the same fields are working well, but new pages wont.Its happening inside wordpress dashboard.
What could be done?

Comment: Please share your code first

Comment: Its not really helpfull as the problem is happening inside the wordpress dashboard. Also, acf wasn't edited by functions.php

Comment: first try to find the error. try var dumping the ACF. What do you get? we need more information on what you have tried and some code would be nice...

Comment: @FernandoSouza without your error or code how can we understand what is the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks all, I will try some var dumping or errors output.